# Facebook API: Upload photo becomes album instead of single post

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm working with facebook API that enable user to upload a photo and give caption(like instagram).
Here is my code to upload photo:

```
$request = (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'POST', '/me/photos', array(
                              'message' => $caption,
                              'url' => $img_url
                            ) ) )->execute();
```

`$result = json_decode($request->getRawResponse(), true);`

If I uploaded more than one photo in the close time, the photos will be grouped in an album instead of a single post.
And facebook will return previous post id, instead of facebook post's id that I have just uploaded.

Is it normal behaviour? Does anyone know how to fix the photo id?

Comment: Photos are always part of an album. I guess you are not actually talking about albums here, but only about how Facebook _displays_ these photos on timeline/in newsfeed? Multiple photos posted to the same album get displayed as grouped in one post, yes. That is expected behavior, and you can only avoid it by leaving more time between the uploads.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So about multiple photos,  this is normal behaviour from facebook. What about facebbok photo id? How do I fix it?

Comment: You should get two values back, `id` and `post_id` – the first one is the photo id, and should be unique.